# Visual Studio : Can't compile with kinect

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect

I'm trying to use the kinect developer kit but i can't compile.
This is my code :

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <NuiApi.h>

using namespace App3;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
using namespace WindowsPreview::Kinect;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON);
    NUI_SKELETON_FRAME ourframe;
    while (1)
    {
        NuiSkeletonGetNextFrame(0, &ourframe);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (ourframe.SkeletonData[i].eTrackingState == NUI_SKELETON_TRACKED)
                cout << "Right Hand: ";
            cout << ourframe.SkeletonData[i].SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_HAND_RIGHT].y << endl;
        }
    }
    NuiShutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

and i have this error (sorry it's in french):

```
LNK2019 symbole externe non résolu __imp__NuiInitialize@4
LNK2019 symbole externe non résolu __imp__NuiShutDown@0
LNK2019 symbole externe non résolu __imp__NuiSkeletonGetNextFrame@8
```

When i added the incudes it worked better but it wouldn't compile.
So i supposed the libs where missing bt even if i add them it still give me these error.

Comment: How are you adding the libraries? Apparently it's wrong, as the linker can't find them

Comment: Link -> General -> Additional libraries 
(i don't know if it's the exact name i translated it from french)

Comment: have you also set the "Additional library directories" to the correct path (where you have the kinect sdk libraries installed)?

Comment: Yes i've set it to the right path.